# Thoughts & questions on custom CPU architecture

Tags: cpu, computer-architecture

I'm designing a CPU architecture. I've come up with a preliminary design:
[image: CPU diagram]

I'd like general thoughts on what I can improve in the design and also I have some specific questions:

- Is it overkill to have every register inputting to the ALU, or is it more sensible to have one input hardwired to, say, A?
- This design is as you can probably tell influenced by the Z80 (hence the register naming). Is it a good idea to base the CPU design off of such an old CPU or does it not make any difference really?
- I've not decided whether to have a simple instruction register or whether to implement a pipeline. What kind of performance gains might I be able to achieve in a simple CPU design like this? i.e. is it worth the extra effort of constructing a pipeline?

Comment: You're getting way ahead of yourself here. You can't design an implementation until you know what your requirements are. You first have to know what instructions you want this CPU to execute -- the Instruction Set Architecture, or ISA. Only then can you start to think about the hardware resources required for implementation (and performance issues).

Comment: "Does it make a difference?" I'd say, of course it does, others might not: that's a purely subjective question. If you want to compare this to modern CPU designs: there's actually a wealth of small RISC-V implementations out there, and some are really well documented.

Comment: "Is it overkill?": How should we tell? For what purpose? What's the problem you're having with this?

Comment: @DaveTweed I have an ISA. Should I have posted it here? It's a little out of date as I've altered the hardware design since then but I could make some changes and repost

Comment: All in all, I congratulate you on starting such a large and educative project! Rest assured that you're not going to build a competitely performant CPU on your first iteration, so maybe don't start with optimizing for performance, but for *realizability*!

Comment: @Jachdich since ISA and CPU design are usually linked, yeah, you should at least have mentioned that.

Comment: For one thing, what is the purpose of this design? Is it just a "toy" for learning, that will only be programmed by hand in machine language? Or do you hope to do real work on this CPU, in which case, you want to think about compatibility with existing software development tools.

Comment: @MarcusMüller that is true that I am probably getting ahead of myself. The truth is that I started out with a very simple design and I can't help adding features :/

Comment: @Jachdich that's one of the challenges engineers in every field encounter every day. Starting small, and staying small until things work is one of the central things engineers need to learn (or at least, I believe that it is, because it's one of the things that I catch myself having to deal with all the time).

Comment: Like DaveTweed asked already.....what is your goal here? The answer to that should and will be a guidepost as to the next steps you need to take.

Comment: @DaveTweed It is mostly a toy, however I will probably be writing at least an assembler and I'm experimenting with a C compiler (I've got a lot to learn though...) so that it might in the future be able to do something like play simple games or maybe even run BBC basic.

Comment: To add to @DaveTweed's comment, once you have designed your ISA and then your architecture, you will know how the ISA influenced the architecture, so you can go back and change the ISA to make it simpler, or faster, and repeat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it overkill to have every register inputting to the ALU, or is it
>   more sensible to have one input hardwired to, say, A?

You will need more 'buffers' and connecting logic to route all the registers to the ALU, so you its a space vs functionality trade off.

> This design is as you can probably tell influenced by the Z80 (hence
>   the register naming). Is it a good idea to base the CPU design off of
>   such an old CPU or does it not make any difference really?

Older CPUs are easier to understand because they have reduced instruction sets and smaller data widths, I would prefer to design with an old CPU if I were implementing this myself.

> I've not decided whether to have a simple instruction register or
>   whether to implement a pipeline. What kind of performance gains might
>   I be able to achieve in a simple CPU design like this? i.e. is it
>   worth the extra effort of constructing a pipeline?

If you don't want to wait for your ALU to complete instructions, you'll want a pipeline.

Comment: think about VLIW, and dump the optimization onto the Compiler.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf, you recommend the OP writes an optimising compiler as well?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf from what I understand, you'd have to be a literal wizard to create a CPU that supports VLIW and probably at least 10 wizards to write a compiler that is fairly performant. Heck, I've never written a C compiler before.

Comment: @Jachdich As far as I understand, a VLIW CPU is simpler because there is no instruction decoder. Writing an ideal optimising compiler may be difficult. Writing a simple compiler that doesn't take advantage of the VLIWness should not be. I don't think it will make the CPU easier to design though - you'll still need to consider what kinds of instructions your compiler will realistically need to generate.

Comment: @user253751 so VLIW is just microcode? In that case, it would be easier to implement in hardware. I'm not 100% sure if it is just microcode but I think theres a chance it's more complex than that.

Comment: @Jachdich (As I understand it) VLIW is a general idea where instead of having the CPU figure out the best way to execute instructions, the instructions tell the CPU *precisely* what to do. So for complicated CPUs, the instructions tend to be very long.

Comment: @user253751 alright I'll look into it. It certainly seems that it would make for a lot more flexibility.

Answer (score -1):

Late to the party.

No it's not crazy.
How did the CPU come along?

My own homebrew CPU SPAM-1 has all registers (everything) going via the ALU.

https://hackaday.io/project/166922-spam-1-8-bit-cpu

There's a YouTube vid on my register files design.

Or ...
https://www.google.com/search?q=spam1+8bit+cpu

The benefit of all regs going via ALU is that you end up with a much more powerful machine language.

Other cpus like the 6502 end up using tax/txa to perform register transfers to get access to the ALU.
But you won't need to waste CPU cycles on that.

Not needing to swap regs means simpler faster code

Comment: This could become an answer, if you explain the decision about connecting all registers to the ALU.

Comment: Done - thoughts?

Comment: Yes, good point